# For PHP is there a significant difference in memory usage if creating new array or adding same indexes to existing array?

Tags: php, arrays

If I am creating an array with several hundred indexes, how much overhead is required for the additional array versus adding a second dimension to an existing array?

I.E. $pages['page']['url'] and $titles['page']['title'] versus $pages['page']['url']['title'] versus $pages['page']['title'], where the last example assumes each index of $pages contains an associative array.

The goal is to be able to be to lookup two attributes of each 'page'. Each 'page' has a 'url' and a 'title', which would be more efficient for memory usage on the arrays? Which for access/storing the data?

Two associative arrays:

```
// Store the information in arrays
$titles['page1'] = 'Page 1 Title';
$titles['page2'] = 'Page 2 Title';

$urls['page1'] = 'http://www.page1.com';
$urls['page2'] = 'http://www.page2.com';

// Display an example
echo $titles['page1'] . ' is at ' . $urls['page1'];
```

or one array of arrays:

```
$pages['page1'] = array( 'title' => 'Page 1 Title', 'url' => 'http://www.page1.com' );
$pages['page2'] = array( 'title' => 'Page 2 Title', 'url' => 'http://www.page2.com' );

// Display an example
echo $pages['page1']['title'] . ' is at ' . $pages['page1']['url'];
```

Comment: I would guess they both add remove new indexes with the same speed, but having 2 separate arrays would take up more memory.

Comment: Could you explain the context?  Why not keep a page object that contains all the info about a page, and index the pages in a single array?

Comment: Your explanation of the array structuring differences is too inexact. A new array takes up at least 200 bytes. Just adding a new key not so much. But in your case it seems you add a new subarray. In which case it doesn't matter. Subarray and a separate array variable take up the same amount.

Comment: You may want to consider creating a Page object so that you can create any number of attributes vs creating 3 layer multi-dim arrays, so you end up with just an array of page objects. I believe this will also reduce your memory footprint as well.

Comment: @mario I shall try and expand the question to be more exact.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision I thought of that after the fact, and if I had to do it again I would do as you suggest. For some reason I never think of objects in PHP.

Comment: @ToothlessRebel Have you checked my updated answer? I think this answers your question now? Please explain, if I'm wrong here.

Comment: got any certain problem with memory usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory usage of a two dimensional array is slightly bigger, but this may result from bad code (?).

```
<!--
    http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

    array1: 116408 (1D 1001 keys)     (1x 100.000 keys:  11.724.512)
    array2: 116552 (2D, 1002 keys)    (2x  50.000 keys:  11.724.768)

    total:    +144                                             +256
-->

<?php

function genRandomString() {
    $length = 10;
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $string = '';    

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }

    return $string;
}

$i = 0;

// ----- Larger 1D array -----
$mem_start = memory_get_usage();
echo "initial1: " . $mem_start . "<br />";
$arr = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
    $arr[ genRandomString() ] = "Hello world!";
}

echo "array1: " . (memory_get_usage() - $mem_start) . "<br />";
unset($arr);

// ----- 2D array -----
$mem_start = memory_get_usage();
$arr2 = array();

echo "initial2: " . $mem_start . "<br />"; 


for ($i = 1; $i <= 500; $i++) {
    $arr2["key______1"][ genRandomString() ] = "Hello world!";
    $arr2["key______2"][ genRandomString() ] = "Hello world!";
}

echo "array2: " . (memory_get_usage() - $mem_start) . "<br />";

unset($arr2);

unset($i);
unset($mem_start)    
echo "final: " . memory_get_usage() . "<br />"; 

?>
```

Comment: @ToothlessRebel My answer was based upon values. Sorry. I did'nt read cloase enough. I fixed my answer now. It's based on keys now.

Answer (score 0):

One array consume less memory than two:

```
 total mem two arrays: 2496
 total mem one array: 1848
```

I do calculations assign 'aaaa' to each element in one and two arrays, capturing [memory_get_usage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php).

EDIT:
CORRECTION: If one of these is one level array, is better two arrays than one.

Added the code. I moddifie it to put more elements to the array and do one array with only one level:

---

total mem two arrays: 1,009,720

### total mem one array: 1,011,112

```
$memI = memory_get_usage();

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
     $pages[uniqid()][uniqid()] = 'aaaa';
     $titles[uniqid()] = 'aaaa';
}

$memF = memory_get_usage();

$memCalc = $memF - $memI;

echo "<pre>total mem two arrays: " . number_format($memCalc);


unset($pages);
unset($titles);

$memI = memory_get_usage();

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    $pages['page'][uniqid()][uniqid()]  = 'aaaa';
    $pages['title'][uniqid()] = 'aaaa';
}

$memF = memory_get_usage();

$memCalc = $memF - $memI;

echo "<pre>total mem one array: " . number_format($memCalc);
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't use twice the amount of elements in two arrays (same amount in each array)? Please check my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes @Smamatti, I'm sure, the question is not if a multilevel array consume more memory than two one level, the question is if a multilevel array consume more memory than two multilevel arrays, note the I.E. section at the middle of the question. In this case, One complex multilevel array consume less memory than two simple multilevel arrays.

Comment: CORRECTION: If one of these is one level array, is better two arrays than one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the difference in multi-dimensional array's vs several arrays would be large enough to focus on it for memory usage, strings and int's however are quite different in memory.

Applying conventions to coding would use less ram.

Using this example:

```
$pages['page1'] = array( 'title' => 'Page 1 Title', 'url' => 'http://www.page1.com' );
$pages['page2'] = array( 'title' => 'Page 2 Title', 'url' => 'http://www.page2.com' );

// Display an example
echo $pages['page1']['title'] . ' is at ' . $pages['page1']['url'];
```

You could re-write it:

```
$pages[] = array('Page 1 Title','www.page1.com' );
$pages[] = array('Page 2 Title','www.page2.com' );

// Display an example
foreach ($pages as $page){
   echo $page[0] . ' is at http://' . $page[1];
}
```

You could also use Definitions for keys for the self-documenting code idea:

```
define("TITLE_KEY", 0);
define("URL_KEY", 1);
$pages[] = array(TITLE_KEY=>'Page 1 Title',URL_KEY=>'www.page1.com' );
$pages[] = array(TITLE_KEY=>'Page 2 Title',URL_KEY=>'www.page2.com' );

// Display an example
foreach ($pages as $page){
   echo $page[TITLE_KEY] . ' is at http://' . $page[URL_KEY];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP don't has really array. PHP technically has a **map**, or sometimes called **associatyve array**. Map speed depends on number of elements, and memory usage doesn't matter on time when you add elements.

Comment: The question seems be be focused on memory usage based upon data structure. Therefore time is not an issue but additional references. There may be a performance difference, because a two-dimensional array may require another lookup (based upon how this is internally implemented in PHP).